# Issues with MariaDB 10.3 development libraries and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, python, mysql, dependencies, mariadb

Trying to install any of the MariaDB 10.3 development library packages for the version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04 seems to result in circular or unmet dependencies. I ran into this when trying to configure a Django (Python) environment for MySQL (MariaDB) support with pip (mysqlclient). It complains about not finding mysql_config, which is part of one of the MySQL (MariaDB) development libraries.

After a few attempts, it seems to come down to some issue with a libc6 version and/or update in Ubuntu 20.04 that makes the entire conflict resolution process throw up hands in the air.

Has anyone else run into this with MariaDB 10.3 and Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Could you post the exact commands you  use and their outputs?

Comment: I gave up and went the PostgreSQL way instead since it has no such issues. Basically, I tried installing "anything" that would give me "mysql_config", such as MariaDB development files and/or MySQL development files. No external repos were configured for this, just the standard Ubuntu repos. So it should be quite simple to reproduce. But it came down to what I think is a libc6 conflict. I did "Google" and found some writings to that effect, but unfortunately, I had to get this resolved "yesterday".